# Cannot see Firebase Analytics from built Unity Android project

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I am trying to link Firebase Analytics to my Unity application and build to Android. My build works and I am able to initialize Firebase + Firebase Analytics and send events, but I cannot see anything in the Firebase Analytics Dashboard (says 0 users active in the last 30 minutes, no events are logged, etc.)

Here is where I initialize Firebase in my application, following their documentation:

```
    private void InitializeFirebase ()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()
            .ContinueWith(
                continuationAction: (Task<DependencyStatus> task) =>
                {
                    DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = task.Result;
                    if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
                    {
                        _FirebaseApp = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                        FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(enabled: true);
                        _LoggingManager.Logger?.Info(content: "Firebase App ready");
                        DisplayAnalyticsInstanceId();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _LoggingManager.Logger?.Error(
                            content: "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);

                        // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
                    }
                });
    }
```

And here's where I log a sample event:

```
private void SendCompletedEvent (CompletedEvent playerEvent)
    {
        _Logger.Warning(content: "Sending event complete event");
        DisplayAnalyticsInstanceId();
        Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
            .LogEvent(name: Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.EventComplete);
    }
```

I build an APK using Unity Cloud Build, and because it doesn't use the latest version of XCode, I have downgraded my Firebase version to 8.1.0. In my adb logs, I see these calls go out (all at their appropriate times):

```
06-30 16:25:34.195 17977 18038 I Unity   : Firebase Analytics API Initializing
06-30 16:25:34.195 17977 18038 I Unity   : analytics API Initialized
06-30 16:25:34.410 17977 18216 I Unity   : Firebase App ready
06-30 16:27:28.310 17977 18038 W Unity   : Sending event complete event
```

So all of these functions are definitely firing, and from what I can tell nothing is complaining. Occasionally, even before I start the program, I do get these errors in adb logs:

```
06-27 15:28:14.770  1305 10260 W FA      : Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id
```

However, I've also been logging my Firebase instance id using the `FirebaseAnalytics.GetAnalyticsInstanceIdAsync()` function, and at least in Unity is shows up as a real and constant number. So I'm not sure if this is logging from other processes on my device.

I'm really confused on what I'm doing wrong. I've imported Firebase Analytics into my project with the google-services.json file that Firebase gave me, and my events seem to be firing correctly.

I also tried adding the SHA-1 number of my device to Firebase adnroid settings, using the command `keytool -printcert -jarfile <package-name>.apk`, which I don't think is necessary because I'm not using sign-in services or app invites. That doesn't seem to be having any effect, either.

Is there anything else I can try? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

OP here, I fixed this by basically starting from scratch-- deleting and then freshly importing my Firebase Library into Unity, deleting the Firebase project in the console and creating a new one, recreating/importing the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and `google-services.json` files. Then, using the same code, my android build would trigger 'Active users' in the Firebase Analytics console.

Good luck to anyone dealing with anything similar!